# What is the purpose of the configuration manager in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm a little unsure about what the purpose of the configuration manaeger is.  To avoid confusion this is what I mean

[image]

In particular I'm interested to know what the point of the point of the Configuration column is.  Why can I set a Debug Configuration, against DataAccess, to Debug when at the top, for the Active solution configuration I have set UAT?  What does all this mean anyway?  What is an active solution configuration and what is a configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Solution Configuration" is a set of overall settings for compiling the projects. Basically, you can have different project settings for different configurations with the most common combination being Release and Debug with, e.g, Release having optimization turned on and Debug having no optimization and having debug symbols exported.

The reason that you can set different Configurations for different platforms is that sometimes you want to break things down more granularly. Let's say that you're testing a release build and everything works fine except the [REDACTED]Domain project. You could set that project into Debug, with the associated symbols and lack of optimization, and then set breakpoints while the rest runs optimzed code.

Clearer?